# How to decrease quality for modeling?

Tags: modeling, animation, vertices

I want to make an animation of some objects, that have a lot of vertices and so Blender gets pretty slow. How can I make the animation without the slow speed in Blender? 
Is there a way to do that easily?

Comment: You could try to enable VBOs (*User Preferences > System*)